# How to install pyserial on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pyserial, raspbian

I want to install pyserial on raspberry pi. But it error.
I do like this:

```
Copy the file into /home/pi
Double click on pyserial-2.7.tar.gz
Choose 'Action'
Choose 'Extract'
double click on pyserial-2.6.tar0
Choose 'Action'
Choose 'Extract'
Open LXTerminal
type cd pyserial-2.7
press Enter
type sudo python setup.py install
press Enter
```

But it error like this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option :'use_2to3'
warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install scripts
changing mode of /urs/local/bin/miniterm.py to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-2.7.egg-info
writing  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-2.7.egg-info
```

What wrong with it? Plese help me fix it. Thanks!

Comment: maybe python 3 is missing? http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=81621&p=577023 read the last reply

Comment: I would use easy_install or pip install to make sure it fulfills all the dependencies. Here is a link how to do it. http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html#from-pypi